# send money direct to customer's bank account using braintree payment gateway

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, braintree

Is there API that directly transfer money to user's bank account using Braintree payment gateway?

I want to transfer money every week. For that I can make cronjob, but want to know is there any API?

I found below from this [link](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/merchant-account/create/php):

```
$merchantAccountParams = [
  'individual' => [
    'firstName' => 'Jane',
    'lastName' => 'Doe',
    'email' => 'jane@14ladders.com',
    'phone' => '5553334444',
    'dateOfBirth' => '1981-11-19',
    'ssn' => '456-45-4567',
    'address' => [
      'streetAddress' => '111 Main St',
      'locality' => 'Chicago',
      'region' => 'IL',
      'postalCode' => '60622'
    ]
  ],
  'business' => [
    'legalName' => 'Jane\'s Ladders',
    'dbaName' => 'Jane\'s Ladders',
    'taxId' => '98-7654321',
    'address' => [
      'streetAddress' => '111 Main St',
      'locality' => 'Chicago',
      'region' => 'IL',
      'postalCode' => '60622'
    ]
  ],
  'funding' => [
    'descriptor' => 'Blue Ladders',
    'destination' => Braintree_MerchantAccount::FUNDING_DESTINATION_BANK,
    'email' => 'funding@blueladders.com',
    'mobilePhone' => '5555555555',
    'accountNumber' => '1123581321',
    'routingNumber' => '071101307'
  ],
  'tosAccepted' => true,
  'masterMerchantAccountId' => "14ladders_marketplace",
  'id' => "blue_ladders_store"
];
$result = Braintree_MerchantAccount::create($merchantAccountParams);
```

But I am not getting what to do with above options.What is routing number and how to use other options?
Can anyone guide me?

Comment: have you get any solution?

Answer (score 4):

No.

Braintree is a *credit card payment* gateway - its purpose is to help you accept credit card payments from customers. It's not a general-purpose financial API, and does not contain any functionality to send or receive bank transfers.

Comment: thank you for reply, but there is an option like **FUNDING_DESTINATION_BANK** which transfers money to bank account. I don't know how but that is the option. I want to know is it possible using that option?

Comment: is it possible that can i sends money from my braintree account to user's bank account once I received in my braintree account using PHP code?

Comment: No. A Braintree account is not like a PayPal account; you cannot store money in the account. The options you're looking at are for configuring where Braintree will send money, probably on a monthly basis, from credit card payments you've received. It can only be set to a bank account you own, at a bank in the USA.

Comment: Additionally: If you're trying to think of clever ways to work around this: DON'T. You are likely to end up violating money laundering laws. This is not something you want to risk.

Comment: thank you for claryfying this thing. is Stripe provides such thing?